# Karatsuba Multiplication using BigInteger

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

I first wrote a code for Karatsuba algorithm using long. It works perfectly I think. Using the same logic I converted the code to BigInteger but for some reasons its giving StackOverflowError.

I cant figure out why. Please help.

---

EDIT1: The code for long also has a logical flaw. I am not sure what.

EDIT2: The code for long works now. I switched a "%" operator with "/" by mistake.

EDIT3: All good now. I changed .xor to .pow and == to .equals and fixed some bracket issues in the return statement. Thank you everyone for the help!

---

Here is the correct code:

```
public static BigInteger karatsuba3(BigInteger i, BigInteger j){
    if (i.compareTo(Ten) == -1 || j.compareTo(Ten) == -1)
        return i.multiply(j);
    String length = getLength(i.max(j));
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(length);
    if (n.mod(Two).equals(One))
        n = n.add(One);

    BigInteger a = i.divide(Ten.pow(n.divide(Two).intValue()));
    BigInteger b = i.mod(Ten.pow(n.divide(Two).intValue()));
    BigInteger c = j.divide(Ten.pow(n.divide(Two).intValue()));
    BigInteger d = j.mod(Ten.pow(n.divide(Two).intValue()));

    BigInteger first = karatsuba3(a,c);
    BigInteger second = karatsuba3(b,d);
    BigInteger third = karatsuba3(a.add(b),c.add(d));

    return ((first.multiply(Ten.pow(n.intValue()))).add ((((third.subtract(first)).subtract( second))).multiply(Ten.pow(n.divide((new BigInteger("2"))).intValue()))).add(second));
}
```

Karatsuba with long code:

```
public static long karatsuba1(long i, long j){
    if (i < 10 || j < 10) 
        return i*j;
    double n = getLength(Math.max(i,j));
    if (n%2 == 1)
        n++;
    long a = (long) (i/Math.pow(10,(n/2)));
    long b = (long) (i%Math.pow(10,(n/2)));
    long c = (long) (j/Math.pow(10,(n/2)));
    long d = (long) (j%Math.pow(10,(n/2)));

    long first = karatsuba1(a, c);
    long second = karatsuba1(b, d);
    long third = karatsuba1(a + b, c + d);

    return ((long) ((first * Math.pow(10, n)) + ((third - first - second) * Math.pow(10, (n/2))) + second));
}

public static int getLength( long a){
    String b = Long.toString(a);
    return b.length();
}
```

Karatsuba with BigInteger code:

```
public static BigInteger karatsuba3(BigInteger i, BigInteger j){
    BigInteger Ten = new BigInteger("10");
    if (i.compareTo(Ten) == -1 || j.compareTo(Ten) == -1)
        return i.multiply(j);
    String length = getLength(i.max(j));
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(length);
    if (n.mod(new BigInteger("2")) == new BigInteger("1"))
        n.add(new BigInteger ("1"));

    BigInteger a = i.divide(Ten.xor(n.divide((new BigInteger("2")))));
    BigInteger b = i.mod(Ten.xor(n.divide((new BigInteger("2")))));
    BigInteger c = j.divide(Ten.xor(n.divide((new BigInteger("2")))));
    BigInteger d = j.mod(Ten.xor(n.divide((new BigInteger("2")))));

    BigInteger first = karatsuba3(a,c);
    BigInteger second = karatsuba3(b,d);
    BigInteger third = karatsuba3(a.add(b),c.add(d));

    return ((first.multiply(Ten.xor(n))).add (((third.subtract(first).subtract( second)))).multiply(Ten.xor(n.divide((new BigInteger("2"))))).add(second));
}

public static String getLength( BigInteger a){
    String b = a.toString();
    return Integer.toString(b.length());
}
```

Comment: On another look you are using the new without delete often. Are you absolutely  sure it is properly deleted after return?

Comment: @Spektre: `I do not see where BigInteger Ten = new BigInteger("10"); is deleted` - wouldn't be the cause due to JRE/JVM garbage collection (on top of no delete to begin with). Not using `java.math.BigInteger.TEN/TWO` is weird - for values that fit `long` (and are not predefined), `BigInteger.valueOf(long val)` would be appropriate. Using 10 (or a power thereof) for divmod is questionable. One _can_ have a peek at most `BigInteger` implementation, sporting Toom-Cook on top of Karatsuba more often than not.

Comment: @greybeard as I mention I do not code in JAVA so I do not know the behavior. Anyway the whole implementation apart learning purposes has no validity as for bigint `*` is used bigint `/,%` and the `pow` is also questionable as it is limiting the input values. Instead halving of used base `WORD`s count is used in the real implementations. The base is never `10` but either a power of `2` or the biggest power of `10` fitting into **ALU** `WORD` used. This converts the whole stuff to just pointer conversion or mem copy.

Comment: I didn't even notice the use of a bit-wise operation where `BigInteger.pow(int power)` would have been appropriate (limits the exponent to int - no deal with bases in the range @Spektre suggests, but one cannot (easily) define `BigInteger.pow(long power)` (outside a JRE implementation).

Comment: Refactor `Ten.pow(n.divide(BigInteger.TWO))` (and `Math.pow(10, n/2)`, at that) into BASE. Use `BigInteger.divideAndRemainder()` in spite of its appalling name.

Comment: (Note that you have `first.multiply()` produce a product about as big as `i.multiply(j)`.)

Comment: You should post each revision of the code along with the edit, otherwise it's confusing as it stands. The edits are supposed to be meaningful updates to the post, not a history of what happened; the latter is captured by the SO site and is available by clicking on the `edit` link below your post. In other words, please do better than making your edits look like `git log`.

Answer (score 4):

In the first snippet, this line looks wrong to me:

```
long d = (long) (j/Math.pow(10,(n/2)));
```

so right now you have `c = d`
probably you want:

```
long d = (long) (j%Math.pow(10,(n/2)));
```

Comment: That was quite dumb of me. Thanks!

Comment: @hsnsd just a typo, it happens ;)

Comment: Can you explain the difference between using .xor and .pow?

Comment: @hsnsd What you want to do there is to split the input number into two halves of almost equal lengths. This can be achieved using integer division and modulo division by appropriate power of 10. You can also use bitmasks to achieve the same result

Answer (score 1):

you have done some mistake when comparing and assigning bigint,so it is the cause for infinite recursive call.

```
if (n.mod(new BigInteger("2")) == new BigInteger("1"))
        n.add(new BigInteger ("1"));
```

should be rectified as;

```
if (n.mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(new BigInteger("1")))
      n = n.add(new BigInteger ("1"));
```

but there are other issues that you should fix it to produce the same result as the "long" version. hope you will be able to rectify them.

Comment: It wasnt working because I was using == instead of .equals at other places. Thank you!

Comment: (Worse, using `==` _might or might not give the intended behaviour_ using `BigInteger.valueOf(4711)`, at least between different JREs (just as with `String` (`intern()`) and primitive type wrappers).)

Answer (score 0):

Use *Ten.pow(x.intValue())* instead of *Ten.xor(x)*

Comment: Whats the difference between .pow and .xor?

Comment: xor() is exclusive disjunction, operation on bitmasks. ie Ten.xor(1) is 11, Ten.xor(2) is 8

Answer (score -1):

This works now

```
public static BigInteger karatsuba3(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {

    // cutoff to brute force
    int N = Math.max(x.bitLength(), y.bitLength());
    if (N <= 2000) return x.multiply(y);                // optimize this parameter

    // number of bits divided by 2, rounded up
    N = (N / 2) + (N % 2);

    // x = a + 2^N b,   y = c + 2^N d
    BigInteger b = x.shiftRight(N);
    BigInteger a = x.subtract(b.shiftLeft(N));
    BigInteger d = y.shiftRight(N);
    BigInteger c = y.subtract(d.shiftLeft(N));

    // compute sub-expressions
    BigInteger ac    = karatsuba3(a, c);
    BigInteger bd    = karatsuba3(b, d);
    BigInteger abcd  = karatsuba3(a.add(b), c.add(d));

    return ac.add(abcd.subtract(ac).subtract(bd).shiftLeft(N)).add(bd.shiftLeft(2*N));
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(karatsuba3(BigInteger.valueOf(12347634456346L), BigInteger.valueOf(23346345643565L)));
}
```

Found the solution here: [Karatsuba Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/99crypto/Karatsuba.java.html)

Now you can compare and see what's going wrong

Comment: what did you use from @rustot answer?

Comment: It compiles but its giving the wrong answer
I tried 12*12 and got 111

Comment: @hunter he changed .xor to .pow from rustot's answer
idk if that makes any difference

Comment: i cant see it,he is still using xor

Comment: @hunter I changed everything to .pow from .xor and now I am getting 1044 for 12*12. Previously i was getting 111
Still not sure where is the error

Comment: Did you check with numbers above 2000 bits ? otherwise your Karatsuba multiplication is not used ... (since you have an `if` for that there)

Comment: I can see the Karatsuba multiplication code in `karatsuba3()` _not_ getting executed from any call where no number is longer than 2000 bits. I can see `karatsuba3()` _not_ making directly recursive calls to `karatsuba3()`.

Comment: This happens to be a copy-paste from somewhere else with no explanation. The only thing it shows is that the author has an internet connection.